# Separate a sentence using Regex

Tags: java, regex

I want to split a sentence using a particular words as a separators

```text
Lun. 08:00 - 12:15 13:15 - 16:15 Mar. 08:00 - 12:15 13:15 - 16:15 Mer. 08:00 - 12:15 13:15 - 16:15 Jeu. 08:00 - 12:15 13:15 - 16:15 Ven. 08:00 - 12:15 13:15 - 16:15 ";
```

as a result i want to have a list like this :

```text
Lun. 08:00 - 12:15 13:15 - 16:15 
Mar. 08:00 - 12:15 13:15 - 16:15 
Mer. 08:00 - 12:15 13:15 - 16:15 
Jeu. 08:00 - 12:15 13:15 - 16:15 
Ven. 08:00 - 12:15 13:15 - 16:15
```

I have started with the regex below :

```java
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("((Lun|Mar|Mer|Jeu|Ven|Sam). [0-9 \\-:]*)");
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(horaires);
while (matcher.find())
{   
    myListe.add(matcher.group())
}
```

But it gives me a result like this :

```text
 matcher.group(1) = Lun. 08:00 - 12:15 13:15 - 16:15 matcher.group(2) = Lun. 08:00 - 12:15 13:15 - 16:15
```

Can any of you help me out please finding the right regex?

Comment: your regex works fine for me. it yields the your desired output

Comment: My regex was fine! Actually how I extracted the result wasn't so good instead of matcher.group(1), I did matcher.group() 
Thank you though for your response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing what you have to this:

```
        String string = "Lun. 08:00 - 12:15 13:15 - 16:15 Mar. 08:00 - 12:15 13:15 - 16:15 Mer. 08:00 - 12:15 13:15 - 16:15 Jeu. 08:00 - 12:15 13:15 - 16:15 Ven. 08:00 - 12:15 13:15 - 16:15 ";
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("((Lun|Mar|Mer|Jeu|Ven|Sam)\\. [0-9 \\-:]*)");
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (matcher.find())
        {   
            list.add(matcher.group(1));
        }

        for(String str : list)
        {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
```

Yields:

> Lun. 08:00 - 12:15 13:15 - 16:15
>   Mar. 08:00 - 12:15 13:15 - 16:15
>   Mer. 08:00 - 12:15 13:15 - 16:15
>   Jeu. 08:00 - 12:15 13:15 - 16:15
>   Ven. 08:00 - 12:15 13:15 - 16:15

EDIT: It seems that I am unable to replicate the situation where your code does not work (I have managed to do it one, but cannot seem to do it again...). Your code worked on my machine, so did the one above.

You can try what I suggested as an alternative approach, so the answer will not be removed, at least not for now.

Comment: since the op accepted this answer it seems he only wanted the whole string, in which case he could also use matcher.group(0) and change the expression to "(?:Lun|Mar|Mer|Jeu|Ven|Sam). [0-9 \\-:]*"

Comment: This works too, But actually using matcher.group(0) or matcher.group(1) gives the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is correct! I have implemented it. It gives the same output which you require. 
See [this demo program.](http://ideone.com/98J3ER)

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("((Lun|Mar|Mer|Jeu|Ven|Sam). [0-9 \\-:]*)");
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(horaires);
while (matcher.find())
{   
    myListe.add(matcher.group())
}

//Iterate your list.
for (String str : myListe) {
      System.out.println(str);
}
```

It gives output:

```
Lun. 08:00 - 12:15 13:15 - 16:15 
Mar. 08:00 - 12:15 13:15 - 16:15 
Mer. 08:00 - 12:15 13:15 - 16:15 
Jeu. 08:00 - 12:15 13:15 - 16:15 
Ven. 08:00 - 12:15 13:15 - 16:15
```

May be you forgot to iterate the list "myListe" data & use matcher.group() instead of matcher.group(1).

Comment: Yes that's exactly what happened, Thank you for your response!